# What is opposite of "inherit" verb from the point of view of parents?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

Consider the expression,

> I inherited mental illness from my parents.

Inheritance means picking up something from parents.

What is the opposite of inheritance, with regards to parents. i.e. when parents give something to their kids, what is it called?

> Mr. Smith "opposite of inherit/gave/placeholder??" mental illness to his kids.

Comment: It's worth noting that idiomatically, native Anglophones  rarely use ***inherit** [from a parent]* with the sense of "acquire genetically". We usually say *He [**gets** his blue eyes from](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+gets+his+blue+eyes+from+his%22) his mother*, rather than ***...inherits** them*.

Answer (score 3):

You could say that a parent "passes on", "passes down", or simply "gives" a trait to his or her children. In a slightly more figurative sense you could say "[bequeath](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bequeath)".